# jQuery ui dialog box do not open in frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, frame

Maybe here someone could help me, because nowhere I can find the answer I need.
I have written custom dialog with jquery UI, but CAN`T open from another file.

this is my that function.

to make more understandable for you. If I want to open confirm box from the same file or function I use

```
var cfg = window.confrim('test');
if(cfg){
   //doSomething;
}
```

but with this dialog I can`t to do nothing.. it's not showing up.. no errors in console everything is included..

and I entering to this function.

```
this.customConfirm = function(window, warning, url){
            var NewDialog = jQuery('<div id="MenuDialog"><p>This is your dialog content, which can be multiline and dynamic.</p></div>');

            NewDialog.dialog({
                modal: true,
                title: "title",
                show: 'clip',
                hide: 'clip',
                position: {at: 'center', my: 'center', of: window},
                buttons: [
                    {text: "Submit 1", click: function() {alert(1);}},
                    {text: "Cancel 2", click: function() {jQuery(this).dialog("close")}}
                ]
            });
            return false;
        }
```

thanks for help :)

Comment: What's wrong? Be more specific.

Comment: sorry for that :) first time asking help :) 
I can reach the function but dialog box is not showed to my window..

Comment: Errors on the console?

Comment: "but with this dialog I can`t to do nothing.. it's not showing up.. no errors in console everything is included."

Comment: You have a typo -- either in your code or in your post. It should be `var cfg = window.confirm('test');`.

Comment: i haven't understand your comment :?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i figure out. So if someone will be needed here the code

```
function customConfirm(warning, okText, cancelText, okCallback, cancelCallback){                
        var NewDialog = myWindow/*here is my window sets*/.jQuery('<div class="custom_confirm" id="custom_confirm" style="display:none;">'+
                        '<div class="custom_confirm_modal">'+
                        '<h4>'+warning+'</h4>');

        NewDialog.dialog({
                modal: true,
                title: this.txt('Attention'),
                show: 'clip',
                hide: 'clip',
                top: '60px',
                position: {at: 'top', my: 'center'},
                resizable: false,
                buttons: [{
                    text: okText,
                    click : function() {    
                        NewDialog.dialog('close');
                        okCallback();
                        }
                    }, {
                    text: cancelText,
                    click: function() {
                       NewDialog.dialog('close');
                        cancelCallback();
                    }}]
            });
        }
```

and usage is like this:

```
customConfirm('My warning message', 'Yes', 'No', function(){
            alert('returned true')
        }, function(){
            alert('returned false');
        });
```